# Create Private Planner plans using graph api

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

How to create Private Plans for a group from graph api.
the plans currently created using the

> POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans
> Content-type: application/json
>
> {   "owner": "ebf3b108-5234-4e22-b93d-656d7dae5874",   "title":
> "title-value" }

this is currently creating a public plan.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "private plan"? The group you specify there determines who can access the Plan.

Comment: Yes, if it is a public plan entire organization can view it

Comment: Provide acess to only those who are added to view the plan

Answer (score 0):

Plans don't have their own separate access control. The access to them is entirely controlled by what they are contained in (in this case, a group). To prevent a plan from being viewed by people outside of a group, the group should be configured to be "private".

Comment: If I keep the visibility of the group to private this might work then